# how to get before and after text in the string which contains 'Or' in it

Tags: c#, string, replace, substring

I want a code that takes a string with 'Or' in it and takes text before and after 'Or' and stores it in seperate variable

I tried the substring function

```
var text = "Actor or Actress";
var result= text.Substring(0, text.LastIndexOf("or"));
```

but with this getting only actor I want actor as well as actress but in seperate variables as a whole word so it can be anything in place of 'actor or actress'

Comment: Use a regular-expression.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use one of the flavors of [**`String.Split`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#overloads) that accepts an array of **string delimiters:**

```
string text = "Actor or Actress";
string[] delim = new string[] { " or " };   // add spaces around to avoid spliting `Actor` due to the `or` in the end
string[] elements = text.Split(delim, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (string elem in elements)
{
    Console.WriteLine(elem);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Actor
Actress
```

**Note:** I am using .NET framework 4.8, but .NET 6 also has an overload of `String.Split` that accepts a single `string` delimiter so there's no need to create `delim` as an array of strings, unless you want to be able to split based on variations like `" Or "`,`" or "`.

Answer (score 0):

Spli() should do the job

```
   text.Split(“or”);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the Split() method

```cs
var text = "Actor or Actress";
Console.WriteLine(text.Split("or")[0]);
Console.WriteLine(text.Split("or")[1]);
```

**Output**

```
Actor 
Actress
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string[] array = text.Split(' ');
foreach (string item in array)
{
    if (item != "or")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Actor 
Actress
```